# How to explain imaginary kinematic viscosity of a vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, complex-numbers, viscosity

According to the connection between the Schrödinger equation and the Navier-Stokes vacuum has the imaginary kinematic viscosity $\frac{ih}{2m}$. How to explain it? For the formation of the viscosity of the vacuum environment is needed, how to describe its properties?

Comment: Evgeniy, why are you posting short questions on this site then immediately answering them yourself?

Comment: This is a very important question about the properties of a vacuum and everything bypasses it.

Comment: This has been considered many times before, eg. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281145/

Comment: The properties of imaginary kinematic viscosity or thermal diffusivity were not considered in this article.

Comment: In this topic, I presented an almost experimental fact obtained from the connection between the solution of the Schrödinger and Navier-Stokes equations. This fact requires an explanation. It doesn't matter if the result is ether, but perhaps dark energy and dark matter. I have only a rough theory on this score. Theorists will respond, this may shed light on the properties of vacuum. The relationship between the solutions of the two equations is described in the topic "How to think about speed or velocity of an electron (in an atom)?"

Answer (score -5):

Honestly, I know the answer to this question, but I can not publish it, it is in Russian. In addition, I wonder what others think about it.
Use the formula for kinematic viscosity for gas. The average particle velocity is set equal to the speed of light in a vacuum. The length of the free path is estimated from the size of the particles describing the medium and their concentration. A particle is considered a multipole consisting of a particle and an antiparticle. The mass of a particle is considered as electromagnetic. The density of a rarefied gas is assumed to be equal to the density of a vacuum of $10^{-29}g/cm^3$. From these relations one can determine the mass of particles and the multipole arm. These are the main ideas. As a result, the relations of quantum mechanics should be obtained, but this cannot be explained on the fingers. This follows from the ratios of the dimension, all values have the dimensions of quantum mechanics, so the dimension of the energy is correct. The coefficient also turns out to be correct.But there are new ratios.

Thank you very much for the information on the relationship between the temperature equation and the Schrödinger equation, and between the Schrödinger equation and bending waves. I did not know about these analogies. But my connection between the Schrödinger and Navier-Stokes equations with the imaginary kinematic viscosity of a vacuum is also valid. But the connection between the definition of temperature and the Schrödinger equation requires an assumption of imaginary time, just as imaginary kinematic viscosity is required. These analogies require new values of the coefficients of vacuum thermal conductivity. I will think about it, and I think the result will be similar to my result.

In fact, the thermal equation looks like this
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\vec V \nabla T=\chi \Delta T+\frac{\nu}{c_p}(\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x_k}+\frac{\partial V_k}{\partial x_i})^2$$
Only in the case of a stationary medium is it similar to the Schrödinger equation. In addition, the time remains valid and not imaginary as described in the proposed article. The coefficient of thermal diffusivity becomes imaginary, and this changes the content of the article. We are looking for a medium with imaginary kinematic viscosity or with imaginary thermal diffusivity. And this is a completely different formulation of the problem.

Comment: I add that the properties of the environment describe dark matter and dark energy. The ratio of the imaginary part of the mass to the real part corresponds to the ratio of the mass of dark energy to dark matter.

Comment: Vacuum is not empty space, it is a rarefied gas with a density $10^{-29}g/cm^3$. Dark matter and dark energy form this density. Dark matter and dark energy consist of vacuum particles discovered and described by me.