# Is the Schrödinger equation the heat equation with imaginary constants?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers, wick-rotation, heat-conduction

Playing around with the Schrödinger equation, I separated the time partial derivative this way:

$$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi$$

Looking at it, I realized that, for a free particle, we have:

$$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}$$

If we call $\frac{i\hbar}{2m}=\alpha$, then:

$$\Psi_t=\alpha\Psi_{xx}$$

Which is exactly in the form of the heat equation: $u_t=\alpha u_{xx}$. Furthermore, the heat equation often contains added terms that indicate a heat loss (or gain), for example: $u_t=\alpha u_{xx}-\beta u$

Comparing to the full Schrödinger equation at the start of this post, it's clear that if $\beta=iV/\hbar$ then the Schrödinger equation is: $\Psi_t=\alpha \Psi_{xx}-\beta \Psi$. Exactly in the form of the heat equation above.

So what's going on here? These equations are too similar for it to be a coincindence: are there fundamental reasons as to why this is the case?

Comment: They are related, however, remember that in quantum mechanics the wave function is also complex, not just the constant $\alpha$

Comment: Are they the same equation: yes, pretty much, although that $i$ in the Schrodinger equation significantly changes the nature of the solutions. Still, they're _so_ similar that a typical way to approach the Schrodinger equation is to make time imaginary, solve the heat equation, and then transform back.

Comment: For another (related) connection between quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics, see Section 2.3 of Tong's [statistical field theory notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html).

Comment: Previously: [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281145), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75363/how-is-the-schroedinger-equation-a-wave-equation), [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236269/connection-between-solution-for-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-and-solution-for-heat-equat).